# Don't know how to set reactivity values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny application that takes in a number of parameters (number of experiments, number of folds for cross validation, and an input data file), a then runs some .R scripts in the background. But I keep getting the following error:

"Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive function.)"

Here's a snippet of the code for my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

experiments <- list(
  "1" = 1,
  "3" = 3,
  "5" = 5,
  "10" = 10,
  "50" = 50
)
folds <- list(
  "1" = 1,
  "3" = 3,
  "5" = 5,
  "10" = 10
)

shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Classification and Regression Models"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("experiments_number", "Choose Number of Experiments:",
                  choices = experiments)
      selectInput("folds_number", "Choose Number of Folds:", choices = folds),
      fileInput(
        "file1",
        "Choose a CSV file:",
        accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'text/plain')
      )
    ),
```

and the beginning of my code for server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    # Server logic goes here.

    experimentsInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$experiments_number,
            "1" = 1,
            "3" = 3,
            "5" = 5,
            "10" = 10,
            "50" = 50)
    })

foldsInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$folds_input,
            "1" = 1,
            "3" = 3,
            "5" = 5,
            "10" = 10)
    })

if (is.null(input$file1$datapath))
                return(NULL)

source("CART.R")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we can't tell anything without seeing what is CART.R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CART.R, you have the line `dataset <- input$file1$datapath`

You are accessing this input slot in server.R, but it is not inside a "reactive context" which is what the error message is telling you.

To get past this error, you have to wrap that inside a reactive function.

```
ds <- reactive({
  dataset <- input$file1$datapath
})
```

and call it with a `ds()`

#### UPDATE

based on OP's request for clarification. Here's one way to do it:

#### In Server.R

```
source("CART.R") #which does NOT access reactive elements
#common functions go here. (non-reactive ones)

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  
  ds <- reactive({
    dataset <- input$file1$datapath
  })
         
  output$rt <- renderText({
    {  ds1 <- ds()
      #now ds1 is available in this function
      Do something with ds1
    }
  })
```

Here's a full example from the Shiny team. [Example 03_reactivity](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/inst/examples/03_reactivity/server.R)
You can run it by typing `runExample("03_reactivity")` once the Shiny library is loaded.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I've wrapped the inputs into reactive functions. But where and how do I call ds() - in server.R or CART.R?

Comment: The reactive function would be called from inside shinyServer, in server.R. For starters, I'd recommend bringing everything in CART.R into server.R. You can use `source` later, if you really need it.

Comment: Thank you.Could you please give me an example how to do this, I've been fiddling round with it, but can't get it to work. :( Also, I really need to use source()...